# Categorize website visitors starting from the first occasion, based on if condition

Tags: google-bigquery, intervals, between, dateadd

Could you please help me with sql statement, preferreby it should work in big query. I have 3 columns userid, date, hostname. I need to create additional column - **client_type** on the following condition: when userid first time comes to hostname = "online-store.com" then from this date on **client_type** for this particular userid will be always "current_client" else "visitor".

For example, in the image (link attached) we have userid = 1 and 4 who had become "current client". User 4 was just a visitor, but after visiting hostname = "online-store.com" he will be always classified as "current client".[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yELcs.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code and most importantly data that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the your problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: take a closer look especially to that part - `Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire code! ..., it likely includes a lot of irrelevant details that readers will need to ignore when trying to reproduce the problem. Here are some guidelines: ...`

Comment: Mikhail, thanks a lot for advice, I have rewritten my question and added a picture. Also my question has been modified a bit.

Comment: see the answer. please in your next/new questions - avoid using images and rather provide data examples as plain text so we can use it while helping you :o)

Comment: ok, =) understand

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  userid, date, hostname,
  IF(0 = COUNTIF(hostname = 'online-store.com') OVER(
    PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ), 'visitor', 'current_client') client_type
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data you provided in your question

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 userid, DATE '2018-02-01' date, 'online-store.com' hostname UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2018-02-01', 'other' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '2018-02-01', 'other' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '2018-02-01', 'other' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-02-01', 'other' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-04-07', 'other' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '2018-04-08', 'online-store.com' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, '2018-04-08', 'other' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, '2018-04-08', 'other' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '2018-04-08', 'other' UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, '2018-04-08', 'other' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-07-07', 'other' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-11-22', 'online-store.com' 
)
SELECT 
  userid, date, hostname,
  IF(0 = COUNTIF(hostname = 'online-store.com') OVER(
    PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ), 'visitor', 'current_client') client_type
FROM `project.dataset.table`
ORDER BY date
```

with result

```
Row userid  date        hostname            client_type  
1   1       2018-02-01  online-store.com    current_client   
2   1       2018-02-01  other               current_client   
3   2       2018-02-01  other               visitor  
4   3       2018-02-01  other               visitor  
5   4       2018-02-01  other               visitor  
6   1       2018-04-07  other               current_client   
7   4       2018-04-08  online-store.com    current_client   
8   4       2018-04-08  other               current_client   
9   5       2018-04-08  other               visitor  
10  6       2018-04-08  other               visitor  
11  8       2018-04-08  other               visitor  
12  1       2018-07-07  other               current_client   
13  1       2018-11-22  online-store.com    current_client
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be good:

```
#standardSQL
with userdates as (
  select userid, hostname, min(date) as mindate from `dataset.table` where hostname = 'online-store.com' group by userid, hostname
)

select u.userid, u.date, u.hostname, case when  u.date >= ud.mindate then 'current_user' else 'visitor' end as client_type
from `dataset.table` u
left outer join userdates ud on u.userid = ud.userid
order by 1, 2
```